# ajax post values is empty

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I wanted to get the data from the ajax post which are the student name and student religion(abdullah and muslim) values in the passwrapper.php and post those values on the console.log. However, i cant find the posted values on the console.log. i want to show those posted values on the console.log.

Here is my code below.... 
orignially my code is about performing ajax post to the passwrapper.php
and then the passwrapper.php include another script, student.php to show all the data on the html file.

HTML FIle

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Cesium-1.34/ThirdParty/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<div id="resulte"</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
showData();
function showData()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "passwrapper.php",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            lastName: 'Abdullah',
            lastReligion: 'Muslim',
        },      
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('An error occurred... Look at the console (F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I, Console tab) for more information!');
            $('#resulte').html('<p>Status Code: '+jqXHR.status+'</p><p>ErrorThrown: ' + errorThrown + '</p><p>jqXHR.responseText:</p><div>'+jqXHR.responseText + '</div>');
            console.log('jqXHR:');
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log('textStatus:');
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log('errorThrown:');
            console.log(errorThrown);
        },

    });
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Passwrapper.php

```
    <?php
include 'student.php';
executePass();

receivePost();
function receivePost()
{
    if ((!isset($_POST["lastName"])) and (!isset($_POST["lastReligion"])))
    {
        //do nothing
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo '<script>console.log("Firstname='.$_POST["lastName"].' lastReligion='.$_POST["lastReligion"].'");</script>';

    }
}

?>
```

student.php

```
<?php
function executePass()
{

    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','netwitness') or die ("Could not connect database");
    $db = mysqli_select_db($conn,'abdpractice') or die ('Could not select database');

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from student");
    $json_array = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $json_array[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($json_array);
}
?>
```

my question is how to post those values abdullah and muslim on the console.

Comment: Try this https://www.google.co.za/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323411/how-can-i-write-to-console-in-php&ved=0ahUKEwjJ7svolO_VAhVhAcAKHQXhBJ4QFggmMAA&usg=AFQjCNGV77WLBpmad3zBII_ygJU7g0J4KA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I write to console in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323411/how-can-i-write-to-console-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<?php
include 'student.php';
executePass();

if ((!isset($_POST["lastName"])) and (!isset($_POST["lastReligion"])))
{
    //do nothing
} 
else 
{
    //post the values(Abdullah and Muslim) on the console.log on the passwrapper.php
    //i do not want to disrupt the executepass()

echo '<script>console.log("Firstname='.$_POST["lastName"].' lastReligion='.$_POST["lastReligion"].'");</script>';

}
?>
```

Comment: about ur code, i saw the post data on the html page console. i receive the error which states ''Status Code: 200

ErrorThrown: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1634

jqXHR.responseText:
 all the data is posted here..

Comment: i want the posted data on the passwrapper.php console log not on the html file

Comment: is it possible not to disrupt the ajax process??

Comment: it's posting on html file because on this ` echo json_encode($json_array);` in the executePass function.

Comment: To post on console instead of html kindly use **echo '<script>console.log("'.json_encode($json_array).'");</script>';**  in place of    echo json_encode($json_array);

Comment: If that doesn't help, kindly  explain exactly what you want to achieve so that we can understand where you're getting it wrong

Comment: ok so basically, the json data(all the data) are posted on the html console page. I want the ajax post value which are Abdullah and Muslim to be posted on the console log as well...

Comment: about the ajax post data, can those two data be posted on the console.log.. Which one can it be posted?? can it be on the passwrapper.php or html file

Comment: i have updated my code and you can see the code .. There is no error and all the data is posted on the html console. however there is no ajax post data.. i cant find the ajax post data on the html file...

Comment: there is no error because i implemented contenttype:"application/json".. what is the purpose of this??

Comment: should i implement $.post in the ajax